# How to Display every 3 results in a row using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html

By using the below code i displayed 9 images, but all images are align side by side, how to display the every 3 images in one row and another3 images in another row ?

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<?php $sel = $db->query("select * from gallery order by gallery_cat_id asc    limit 1,1"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel)){ ?>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody><?php $sel1 = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT ( i.gallery_album_id ) 
FROM mov_gallery_album AS a, mov_gallery_images AS i
WHERE a.gallery_album_id = i.gallery_album_id
AND a.gallery_cat_id =".$row['gallery_cat_id']."
ORDER BY a.gallery_album_id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 9 "); if(mysql_num_rows($sel1)>0){ ?>
</tr><tr>

<?php 
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sel1)){
$dis1 = $db->getRow("select * from ".ALBUMS." where gallery_album_id=".$row1['gallery_album_id']." limit 0,1"); 
$dis2 = $db->getRow("select * from ".GALLERY." where gallery_id=".$dis1['gallery_id']." limit 0,1"); 
$dis3 = $db->getRow("select * from ".ALBUMSIMAGES." where gallery_album_id=".$row1['gallery_album_id']." limit 0,1"); 
$dis4 = $db->getRow("select * from ".GALLERYCATEGORY." where gallery_cat_id=".$dis2['gallery_cat_id']." limit 0,1"); 
?>

<td align="left" width="100%"><table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr><td align="center" height="8" valign="middle" width="80">
<div style="border:0px;clear:both;padding-bottom:100px;margin-left:-110px;">
<div class="image_stack1"><a href="<?php echo SITE; ?>album/<?php echo  ucfirst($dis1['gallery_cat_id']); ?>/<?php echo ucfirst($dis1['gallery_id']); ?>/<?php echo ucfirst($row1['gallery_album_id']); ?>/">
<img id="photo3" src="<?php echo SITE; ?>uploads/gallery/<?php echo $dis4['folder']; ? >/<?php echo $dis2['folder']; ?>/<?php echo $dis1['folder']; ?>/thumb/<?php echo   $dis3['image']; ?>"width="80" height="80">
<div class="namehover1"><?php echo substr(ucfirst($dis1['name']),0,13); ?></div>
</a></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td><?php } ?></tr><tr><td class="midtitle" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding-right: 10px;" align="right" colspan="4"><a href="<?php echo SITE; ?>gallery/<?php echo ucfirst($row['gallery_cat_id']); ?>/" class="midtitle">
<img src="http://www.img./viewall.png" border="0"/>
</a></td></tr><?php } ?></tbody></table></td></tr><?php  } ?></tbody></table>
```

Comment: please format you code. it is unreadable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be wise to use div rather than table. 
Some lines of css would do the trick. You wont have to logically determined to move to next line after 3 images. Here's how you can do with this in css
Lets have a div container for the all the images.

```
<style>
#photo_wrapper {
    width:600px;
}
.photo {
width:150px;
height:150px;
display:block;
float:left;
border:6px #c5d0d6 solid;
margin-right:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<div id="photo_wrapper">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="photo"/>
    <img src="image.jpg" class="photo"/>
    <img src="image.jpg" class="photo"/>
    <img src="image.jpg" class="photo"/>
    <img src="image.jpg" class="photo"/>
    <img src="image.jpg" class="photo"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is generally done with the modulo (remainder after division) operator:

```
foreach ($results as $nr => $row) {
  if (($nr % 3) == 0) echo '<tr>';
  ...
  if (($nr % 3) == 0) echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept is simple, use a counter and each time `this counter MOD 3 is zero` , start a new line.Or just count until 3 and reset the counter.

```
$i = 1;
while( $data = ....)
{
  if($i == 1)
  {
   echo "<tr>"; //new line
  }

 echo "<td> .... </td>";

  if($i == 3)
  {
    $i = 1;
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  else
  {
   $i++;
  }
}

//IMPORTANT! PLEASE NOTICE TO THIS PART: (OUT OF THE LOOP)
if($i < 3)
 echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: No. Now you have the knowledge of `how to do it`. It's your job to do it. Are you looking for an answer or for `do it for me thing`?

Comment: i used your code, then it displays only 2 for row, not 3 , so i asked you

Comment: If so , try to change: `$i = 1;` at the top and in the condition to `$i = 0;` , also change the condition , from `$i == 1` to `$i == 0`

Answer (score 0):

you can put 9 photos in a div, then fix the width of that div to make it enough for only 3 photos in a line. And set float:left; for img tag in CSS.